# Where is Robert Recorde's grave?

Tags: 16th-century, mathematics, famous-people

Where is buried [Robert Recorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Recorde)?

He was a mathematician, he lived in today's England. He died in 1558 in London.

I tried a search on the findagrave website, but there is no entry for his name.

I have found a memorial to him in the St. Mary's Church, Tenby, Wales, but I don't know if he is also buried there.

EDIT: [According to this website, his burial details are unknown.](https://biography.wales/article/s11-RECO-ROB-1558)

Comment: This question might call for either a self-answer, or [perhaps eventual closure for being too basic](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/626/26786): since ["His burial place is unknown."](https://biography.wales/article/s11-RECO-ROB-1558) seems an easily found & reliable site? Please explain why this info might be 'not enough'/'untrustworthy'?

Comment: It seems like a trustworthy site. Thank you.

Comment: Please either [edit] this info into your Q (if you expect better sources to eventually come by) or indeed self-answer (no matter how unsatisfactory such 'we do not know' stuff may at first appear. At least it adds to Wikipedia's empty space about this…) // Comments are not the place for answers and ephemeral/easily gone etc.